# How to implement onReset with Cordova?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am interested on how to implement the onReset method to know when my plugin in reseted.

As seen in Cordova guidelines at ***[Plugin Initialization and Lifetime](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20iOS_plugin_initialization_and_lifetime)***

> Plugins with long-running requests, background activity such as media playback, listeners, or that maintain internal state should implement the onReset method to clean up those activities. The method runs when the UIWebView navigates to a new page or refreshes, which reloads the JavaScript.

So far I've found no documentation on how to implement it nor guidelines anywhere...

If someone knows a way to do it I'd be happy to know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution in iOS, this has to be done on the native side of the plugin and not the JS side...

Cordova **CDVPlugin** implements a `- (void)onReset` method called by a notification center observer `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onReset) name:CDVPluginResetNotification object:theWebView];`

This notification is posted by Cordova each time `webViewDidStartLoad` is triggered.

Since my plugin is a subclass of CDVPlugin : `@interface MyPlugin : CDVPlugin`, I can then override `onReset` method in my plugin class and do the stuff I want :

```
- (void)onReset
{
  //... my code
  [super onReset];
}
```